# Mysql Query Suggestions to get at least master table data

Tags: mysql

I have two tables for getting push settings

1) Push Type : which defines the type of push and there status (0,1)

[image]

2) Push Setting : Having setting for per user

[image]

I am running this query :

```
SELECT `push_type`.*, `push_setting`.`app_id`, `push_setting`.`thumb`, 
    `push_setting`.`video`, `push_setting`.`text`, 
    `push_setting`.`notification_status`, `push_setting`.`email`, 
    `push_setting`.`ios`, `push_setting`.`android`, 
    `push_setting`.`message` 
FROM (`push_type`) 
LEFT JOIN `push_setting` ON `push_type`.`id` = `push_setting`.`push_type_id` 
WHERE ( (push_setting.app_id is NULL ) or (push_setting.app_id = **130** )) AND `push_type`.`status` = "1"
```

130 is User id. And because push_settings have entries of 130 , it gives me all the three records .

but if I come with 144 (another user id ) then it do not show anything. i need to have all the 3 active records in every case.

For the First time , it works fine , I mean if there is no entry in push_setting then it gives me 3 records as the join is not successfull.

Comment: why do you want app_id 130 or NULL, if your requirement is just for 130 ?

Do you have record for 144? The query seems good to me....

Comment: You can shorten the or to (coalesce (push_setting.app_id,130)  = 130 )

Comment: because for the first time , i want to show the 3 records of push type atleast.. if user do some action then it makes an entry in push settings

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query